# Swift ISO 20022 open source parser

Tags: java, swift-mt

I am working on project using Java and I'm looking for open source library to parse swift messages: ISO 15022 and 20022.
for 15022 I already find a solution which is Prowidesoftware, but for 20022 I didn't find anything.
any ideas?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have searched a lot for this about a year ago, but could not find, so we have made our own parser using XPath.It is a tiresome job, but will be helpful in understanding the structure more closely.

Answer (score 9):

**November 2020 Update:**

The Prowide ISO 20022 library is now **open source**.
Distributed with Apache license and including features for:

- Java model for ISO 20022 MX (for example: MxPacs00800109 class, for all MX categories)
- Parser from XML into Java model
- Builder API from Java to ISO 20022 XML
- Conversion to JSON
- JPA model for persistence
- Support for multiple application headers: ah$v10, head.001.001.01, head.001.001.02

Info and download at: https://www.prowidesoftware.com/products/iso20022

The open source covers all categories, variants and versions of the ISO20022.

While restricted ISO versions such as SEPA, CBPR+, SIC or TARGET are provided as complementary comercial packages.

---

I've deleted the outdated previous answer. I'm one of the Prowide libraries authors.

Comment: Hi, yes it is. Take a look at https://www.prowidesoftware.com/products/iso20022

Comment: Hi, is there a way to use Prowide ISO20022 without all the SWIFT things? I'm using EBICS instead and I juste need a way to create ISO20022 files (camt.xxx and pain.xxx).

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by SWIFT things? The ISO20022 model can be use to parse or create any ISO 20022 message regardless of SWIFT/MX. And you can also package it to just use a couple of message categories and not the whole thing.